# Is there a way to make the execution phase of a Gradle task execute during the configuration phase of the project?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, gradle-plugin

I have developed a custom gradle plugin that contains a task which is responsible for populating sensitive files in my project when it is executed. Other gradle tasks (such as tasks that handle running tests or building the application), which require the sensitive files to run properly during their own execution can use `dependsOn` to invoke the custom task and obtain the sensitive files that are needed.

I am using a separate plugin task in my `build.gradle` file that requires the presence of the file(s) during it's configuration phase. More specifically, it is a docker task that requires the filepaths for volumes to exist during it's configuration phase. The configuration phase of the project is always failing due to the failing configuration phase of the docker task (which is because the needed files have not been populated by the execution phase of my task).

My question is: is there a way to make the contents of my `@TaskAction` method of my task execute during the configuration phase? Or make the `docker` task dependent upon my custom task in it's configuration phase rather than in its execution phase? Perhaps the logic of my task should be moved to only execute in the configuration phase in the first place?

Comment: I think the best approach is to see if you can fix the Docker tasks so they don't fail during configuration. What plugin are you using for it?

Comment: @BjørnVester thanks for the reply! I agree that it would be best to fix the Docker task. I am using the plantir docker gradle plugin: https://github.com/palantir/gradle-docker. Specifically the `dockerRun` Exec task: https://github.com/palantir/gradle-docker/blob/develop/src/main/groovy/com/palantir/gradle/docker/DockerRunPlugin.groovy. Any ideas how I could stop this from throwing an exception in the configuration phase?